# Azure Storage Spaces Direct (S2D) Cluster Deployment Fails due to "nic was not found"

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage, azure-deployment

I'm attempting to deploy a new Storage Spaces Direct cluster, but I keep getting a failure in about 1 minute after the deployment starts saying:

`New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 10:01:05 AM - Resource Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces 'XXXXXXXX-1-nic' failed with message '{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidResourceReference",
    "message": "Resource /subscriptions/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/resourceGroup-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/virtualNetwork-vnet/subnets/subNet-snet referenced by resource /subscriptions/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
81/resourceGroups/resourceGroup-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/XXXXXXXX-1-nic was not found. Please make sure that
the referenced resource exists, and that both resources are in the same region.",
    "details": []
  }
}'`

---

Here is the call I am making in the AzureRM powershell module (back-ticks removed for obvious reasons):

`New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment 
 -Name "name" 
 -ResourceGroupName "resourceGroup-rg" 
 -TemplateUri https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/301-storage-spaces-direct/azuredeploy.json 
 -namePrefix "name" 
 -storageAccountType "Premium_LRS" 
 -vmSize "Standard_DS3_v2" 
 -vmCount 2 
 -vmDiskSize 1023 
 -vmDiskCount 5 
 -existingDomainName "domain.com" 
 -adminUsername "adminUsername" 
 -adminPassword $secPassword 
 -existingVirtualNetworkRGName "resourceGroup-rg" 
 -existingVirtualNetworkName "virtualNetwork-vnet" 
 -existingSubnetName "subNet-snet" 
 -sofsName "fs02" 
 -shareName "data" 
 -Verbose`

---

Is there anything obvious that I am missing? Isn't this deployment supposed to deploy the 'nic' as well?

Comment: The error shows that the interface which referenced to your subnet does not exist in the same region. So you should check your subnet in the template. And if you can provide your template and that will be helpful.

Comment: The template is here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/301-storage-spaces-direct/azuredeploy.json

Comment: I already have a cluster deployed to the same resourceGroup, vnet, and snet; so I'm unconvinced the location of these resources is the problem.

Comment: Does the interface in the same region with the vnet? And you just define the variables in the template that you shows. What about the main template.